# A trustworthy Free Open Source Software kit for computer security

Tags: gratis, open-source, security, antivirus

I need some advice on a software kit that I can trust to help secure my computer. It should:

- Be free and open source
- Support Anti-Virus/Malware Protection
- Provide full disk encryption and file encryption
- Have a Firewall

Can you recommend me a trustworthy security kit? Because I do not want to end-up using or downloading any softwares that may contain anything malicious

Comment: Hello! You should really edit your question to include more details, such as your operating system, what exactly happened, etc. It would help us a lot to understand your case.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). Please [edit] your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way. Apart from that, we only recommend "literally anything" when its requirements were described clearly, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: When I want new, free s7w,t he first place I go is always techsupport alert, where the s/w is reviewed. take a look at http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/probably-best-free-security-list-world.htm

Comment: @Testerhood I'm using Ubuntu and Win8 as I am getting used to using the command line and feel of linux. I'm just tired of norton so I wanted to try something new.

Comment: @Izzy The one question is about "recommendations on trustworthy Free Open Source Software for computer security." The list are just subsets of computer security but compsec is the topic at hand... I'm new to Stack, I'll ask more well formed questions in the future.

Comment: @Mawg Thanks dude, This is the first I've heard of techsupportalert, I will browse it to my hearts content.

Comment: @Quantum88 That's way to broad for this site, sorry. For a general discussion, a forum is much better suited. This site here is [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154), but a Q&A site – which works a little different. Just check the links from my previous comment for details. Nevertheless, enjoy your stay!

Comment: `CAUSE I'D END UP DOWNLOADING A ROOTKIT W/O YOUR HELP!!!` Number one step would be to train yourself to prevent this from happening in the first place. Any security software can complement your actions but the first line of defense is always **common sense**. No antivirus can prevent you from trashing your computer if you literally click, download and install everything you come across without thinking twice.

Comment: @Quantum88 Though Timmy already did your job in [edit]ing your question, you should at least add the operating system that software should run on. Mentioning "Anti-Virus" *for me* clearly points to Windows (as there are no viruses for other "major systems"), but some people confuse "virus" with the more generic term "malware" (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus): a core characteristic of a computer *virus* is it replicates itself) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of applications which I can recommend by personal experience and by postings from other people around here. You need to know, sadly not everything is open source, but it doesn't necessarily destroy it's security.

Open Source:

- [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) - It's open source and you can run [virtual machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) with it. Good use cases are for example testing applications where Sandboxie would reach it's limits, like theme patchers changing your Windows files. The first time it's maybe more difficult than Sandboxie, because you need an ISO image of an operating system to install. Here are official legit Windows 7 ISO links from Microsoft: http://www.techverse.net/download-windows-7-iso-x86-x64-microsofts-official-servers/
- [TrueCrypt](http://filehippo.com/download_truecrypt/11601/). Officially abandoned, but still useful for mass file encryption if you are using Windows 7. Many people believe it's still secure and that it got officially taken down because of "**n**ot **s**ecure **a**s" according their [website](http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads). A successor of TrueCrypt is [VeraCrypt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/veracrypt/).
- [KeePass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/) is a password manager. Probably explains itself, it's a cool project.
- [ClanWin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clamwin/) is an anti-virus scanner. From my experience I have heard that it's detection rate isn't very great compared to commercial / closed source anti-virus programs, but at least it's open source.

The list [continues here](http://sourceforge.net/directory/security-utilities/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/), there are pretty many :) I'm currently not aware of a neat open source firewall for Windows.

Closed source:

- [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com) - It's **not** open source, but incredible useful for Windows systems. You can run and install programs inside a sandbox, where all changes will remain in the sandbox. This is great if you would like to test a program, if you believe a program isn't trustworthy or could harm your system files, or for internet browsers in general. It's free for personal use and if you're going to use just one sandbox at a time.
- Windows has a built-in firewall, but generally doesn't offer popups for any internet activity. [Windows 8 Firewall Control](http://www.sphinx-soft.com/Vista/index.html) makes use of the existing firewall, while providing such popup windows, easy connection templates like for example "LAN only", "Peer to Peer", "Disable all". It's free, but the free Plus version likes to open up a popup reminder.
- [Avast Free Antivirus](http://www.avast.com/index) is, as the name says, an antivirus program. It has always done a good job from my experience, with not many false positives. Compared to programs like Kaspersky Internet Security, it's lightweight, which was a pleasure when I did the switch in 2011.